# d3 js renders plot in html generated by local server but not by GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, d3.js

I am using d3 js to plot an area curve -- it renders the plot well when the HTML is generated on local server (running w/ Django). But when ported to GAE, the resulting HTML produces "scrambled" version of the plot.

Since the plotting of a curve is done by javascript (d3) and is entirely dependent on browser (which is same in both cases), I am thoroughly confused as to what can be the source of this error. Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm self-answering: Hopefully this will be useful to someone.

After comparing two HTML files I realized that the way GAE created python dictionary/list that I was passing to HTML led to re-ordering of "dates" and D3 wants dates in order. So a simple

.sort()

on server side before passing data to client side solved the problem.